# Чтение/запись Excel файлов на С# при помощи epplus на sharepoint

Tags: c#, excel, epplus, sharepoint-online

Стоит задача:

> Взять данные из одного Excel файла и переместить в другой оба файла находятся на SharePoint. В наличии имеются адреса этих самых файлов.

На локальном диске эту задачу я выполнил, однако если указать адреса SharePoint, то программа выдает ошибку на строке:
`double copiedData = Convert.ToDouble(fromWorksheet.Cells["A1"].Value);`

Ошибка: `System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' fromWorksheet was null.` Т.е. не находит сам файл, насколько я понял... Как поправить код, что бы файлы были читабельны?

Мой код:

```
using System;
using OfficeOpenXml;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

namespace ExcelTrouble
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;


            string fileFrom = "https://iweof.sharepoint.com/:x:/t/o365g_Adress1"; //адрес с гигантским количеством символов для исходного файла
            string fileTo = "https://iweof.sharepoint.com/:x:/t/o365g_Adress2"; //адрес с гигантским количеством символов для файла куда нужно расположить данные

            ClientContext context = new ClientContext(fileTo);

            using (var fromContext = new ExcelPackage(fileFrom)) 
            {
                ExcelWorksheet fromWorksheet = fromContext.Workbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"];
                double copiedData = Convert.ToDouble(fromWorksheet.Cells["A1"].Value); 

                using (var toContext = new ExcelPackage(fileTo))
                {
                    ExcelWorksheet toWorksheet = toContext.Workbook.Worksheets["DATA"];
                    toWorksheet.Cells["A1"].Value = copiedData;

                    context.Web.Update();
                }

            }

        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Текст ошибки вставьте и в какой строке возникает

Comment: Строка:
double copiedData = Convert.ToDouble(fromWorksheet.Cells["A1"].Value);
Ошибка:
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
fromWorksheet was null.
Если выше написать:
ExcelWorksheet fromWorksheet = fromContext.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet2");
то вроде как ошибки не будет.
Как можно сделать так, что бы он таки увидел этот лист?

Comment: Вставьте это прямо в пост, его можно редактировать.

Comment: Учёл замечание. )

Comment: Файл он находит, а вот воркшита `Sheet1` в нем видимо нет.

Comment: Я проверял, был лист, пробовал добавлять (через Add) и создавал... не работает, видимо, неправильно определяю именно путь. Потому как, повторюсь, в случае с локальными данными все работает. Видимо с SharePoint есть подвох.